# How using MeshTopology.Lines in Unity 4

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to draw lines grid in 3d  Unity.
I found that i can draw lines using MeshTopology.Lines in Unity 4.

But I can not found example how do it with MeshTopology.Lines.
How draw lines in Unity 3d?

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh.SetIndices.html?from=MeshTopology

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3[] verts = new Vector3[]{Vector3.up, Vector3.right, Vector3.down, Vector3.left};
int[] indicesForLineStrip = new int[]{0,1,2,3,0};
//int[] indicesForLines = new int[]{0,1,1,2,2,3,3,0};
Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
mesh.vertices = verts;
mesh.SetIndicies(indicesForLineStrip, MeshTopology.LineStrip, 0);
//mesh.SetIndicies(indicesForLines, MeshTopology.Lines, 0);
mesh.RecalculateNormals();
mesh.RecalculateBounds();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another recommendation -
Initialize a mesh, triangles, vertices, etc. etc. What worked for me was to then do the following (where meshMaterials is an array of materials, material 0 -> submesh 0, and material 1 -> submesh 1):

```
    mesh.subMeshCount = 2; 
    GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials = meshMaterials; 
    mesh.SetIndices(triangles, MeshTopology.Lines, 1);
```

Useful discussion [How to Render/Draw mesh lines OVER texture at runtime/play mode](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-render-draw-mesh-lines-over-texture-at-runtime-play-mode.483504/)